# Django ORM - join a subquery

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have to translate this query into Django ORM, but can't seem to get to it.

I tried about every annotate/values/filter combination I could find, but I never got it to a JOIN like that (nor to correct results). I have not (yet) tried defining a custom Manager though.

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.name,
    dt.deadline
    dt.deal_id
FROM
    dealtask dt
    JOIN task t
    ON dt.task_id = t.id
    JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(deadline) as min_deadline, task_id
        FROM dealtask 
        GROUP BY task_id
    ) dt2
    ON dt.task_id = dt2.task_id
WHERE dt.deadline = dt2.min_deadline
```

My models are the following :

```py
class DealTask(models.Model):
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    deal = models.ForeignKey('Deal', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey('Task', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I want to query : for every Task t, the nearest-deadline DealTask dt related to it, and the Deal related to that dt.

Is this query possible in Django ORM ? In a constant number of queries, I mean.

Also, if you find a simpler query that expresses the same thing, I'm all ears.

Comment: Why not just use a raw query? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#raw

Comment: My solution right now is a raw query. 
But it loses some of the ORM magic, and I have to instantiate the models myself, so I was wondering if it was possible without `raw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be tough to reproduce that exact query. However, you can manage the results in one query, but the generated sql isn't clean. And you don't have access to all of the deal properties.

```
Task.objects.annotate(
    deal_id=Subquery(
        DealTask.objects.filter(
            task_id=OuterRef('id')
        ).order_by('deadline').values('deal_id')[:1]
    ),
    deadline=Subquery(
        DealTask.objects.filter(
            task_id=OuterRef('id')
        ).order_by('deadline').values('deadline')[:1]
    )
)
```

Comment: That seems to work. 
You'd simply have to add in more subqueries to get more related fields, and the `values` call allows you to traverse foreign keys as well.

The only sad part is that it uses more subqueries than needed. Depending on how connected the tables are, this should work okay, though.

Comment: You might be able to use a Prefetch object too.

Comment: To be able to get more fields, you could use JSONBuildObect: